# Группировка сообщений в MySql-запросе

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Прошу помощи в создании запроса. Необходимо при выборке сообщений с базы данных сгруппировать их. Формат вывода такой:

```
[user1-user2]
      [массив сообщений]
[user1-user3]
      [массив сообщений]
[user1-user10]
      [массив сообщений]
```

Вот такой мой запрос:

```
$messages = MessageModel::select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN creator > receiver 
                                                                 THEN CONCAT(creator, "-", receiver)
                                                                 ELSE CONCAT(receiver, "-", creator)
                                                                 END
                                                                 AS user_pair'))
            ->where('creator', session()->get('user_id'))
            ->orWhere('receiver', session()->get('user_id'))
            ->groupBy('user_pair')
            ->get();
```

Запрос группирует пользователей по парам, но мне нужно помимо этого выбрать сами сообщения. Благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Ну так и добавьте сообщения в список выбираемых полей. Обернув их в GROUP_CONCAT(). Или там в JSON_CONCAT()... в общем, по потребности.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за наводку, функции JSON_CONCAT не нашёл, воспользовался JSON_OBJECT

Comment: *функции JSON_CONCAT не нашёл* Пардон, JSON_ARRAYAGG(). Или JSON_OBJECTAGG().